# How to perform a basic full rank factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

What is the general process for performing full rank factorization on a matrix?

For example, if I am given $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1\\ 
 4& 2\\ 
6 &3 
\end{bmatrix}$$

What operations do I perform on this matrix, to get the following solution?
$$=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2 
\\3 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
2 &1 
\end{bmatrix}=BC$$

I ask, because if I am given a different $A$ matrix, where the factorization isn't so obvious, I would like to know the best method to achieve full-rank factorization!

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that.

Comment: Consult https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization#Construction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Find a basis for the row space
- Write the rows as linear combinations of basis elements

or

- Find a basis for the column space
- Write the columns as linear combinations of basis elements